# Closing form from event raised on different thread

Tags: c#, forms, camera, thread-safety, video-capture

I am just trying to make a simple program that starts, makes screenshot from my camera and closes. I am using Aforge.net but my camera does not have any SnapshotCapabilities, so I have to use     VideoCapabilities. I have this simple code:

```
namespace Make_picture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice cam;
        private Image img;
        private int ind = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        }

        private void CameraStart()
        {
            cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[ind].MonikerString);
            cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
            cam.Start();
        }


        private void CameraStop()
        {
            if (cam != null)
            {
                if (cam.IsRunning)
                {
                    cam.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            img.Save("image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            cam.NewFrame -= new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
            this.Close();

            //this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { this.Close(); });
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CameraStart();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraStop();
        }
    }
}
```

I have issue to close program after first new frame is fired. It says that I cannot close it on this thread because form was created on another (`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`). Searching stack exchange I have tried also this:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { this.Close(); });
```

but it does not work either (no exception, but form keeps hanging and I cannot do nothing with him). Could you help me with this issue?
Really thanks.

Yann

PS: I am not a programmer, so this could be done a lot differently I guess. But I think this could work If I knew how to kill the form :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `Invoke()` call to close the form.  You could try calling `CameraStop()` before attempting to close the form.

Comment: [Program wont close and aforge camera keeps running, threading trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13802331/3110834)

Comment: Standard deadlock, always a problem with Invoke().   The camera software isn't going to be very happy about you calling Stop() while its NewFrame event has not finished executing yet.  Use BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke().

Comment: BeginInvoke() worked, thanks for help :)